# ios: how to fix memory warning issue when showing lots of thumbnails(over 3000) by using NSCache?

Tags: ios, url, photos, nscache, memory-warning

I write a **table view**/**collection** view to show lots of photo.
I use **dispatch queue** to load photo from Internet and use **NSCache** to cache photo (for not loading photo from internet again).

when I loaded over 2000 photo, app **received memory warning**.
I tried to release the content of nscache in didreceiveMemoryWarning(), or set the nscache delegate to let nscache to auto release nscache content.

after releasing the content of nscache and I scrolled to the top of the table view,

- sometimes: the thumbnail load different images several times (show
  image1, image5, image 6)
- sometimes: the thumbnail won't show anything

I guess what caused this happened is --> using dispatch queue to show thumbnails in table view

but I don't know how to fix it!!

anyone knows?
or is there any better way to show lots of photos(over 3000)?

thank you!!

Comment: My first thought: Think about using a library for your image handling like SDWebImage. It does exactly what you need and is really easy to use.

Comment: thank you for your replying, I am going to take a look at it!look like very easy!!!